# Using COM in R language

Tags: com, r, ole

I am trying to get the rcom package for R working.  It seems to have installed ok:

```
> install.packages("rcom");
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 'http://mira.sunsite.utk.edu/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/2.9/rcom_2.2-1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 204632 bytes (199 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 199 Kb

package 'rcom' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded packages are in
        C:\Users\solomon\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpzb5oi4\downloaded_packages
updating HTML package descriptions
```

Then I try to run something:

```
>comCreateObject("Excel.Application");
Error: could not find function "comCreateObject"
```

What am I missing, the [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rcom/rcom.pdf) tells me that comCreateObject is the appropriate command.  However, the manual's version is somewhat old.  Anyone else have any insights?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can see a couple of potential problems here - rcom has a weird installation.

1. Did you load the package - that is, run `library(rcom)` after installing it?  I know, I know - but I forget that step all the time, and it would definitely give you the "could not find function" error.
2. Did you run the `installstatconnDCOM()` command?  I almost didn't notice it telling me to do this.

Comment: That helped me get started.  However, it got more complex.  I had an old version of R and some DCOM for R installer that prevented statconnDCOM from installing.  Also, for some reason, the version of rcom was old from the mirror I was using.

Note:  sysinternals DebugViewer is your friend for RCOM.

Comment: For clarification, comCreateObject works even when installstatconnDCOM() failed.  So, it appeared that statconnDCOM actually installed okay.